# Build an app on Heroku using Go Module. change the root directory

Tags: go, heroku, build

I choose the way [Go Module Specifics](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-go/blob/9a9d53d/README.md#go-module-specifics) to build my Go app.

When I set the directory like below, it works well.

```
main.go
go.mod
go.sum
README.md
```

where go.mod

```
module xxx

// +heroku goVersion go1.18
go 1.18
...
```

But I want to put the all source code in the src folder. and push to Heroku, it will wrong

```
README.md
 src
  - main.go
  - go.mod
  - go.sum
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `go.mod` (and `go.sum`) files **need to be in the codebase root directory**. Buildpack will search the codebase for `main` package(s) and compile them all. You can override this behavior (what get's build) by using `+heroku install` build directive:

> When using go modules, this buildpack will search the code base for main packages, ignoring any in vendor/, and will automatically compile those packages. If this isn't what you want you can specify specific package spec(s) via the go.mod file's // +heroku install directive (see below).

```
README.md
- go.mod
- go.sum
 src
  - main.go
```

I don't think you can use Go Module Specifics with `go.mod` file on deeper level than root in Heroku but your code can indeed be in subdirectory.

Comment: Thanks that helps. Before this, I thought that `go.mod` and `go.sum` needed to be put together with `main.go`, but it's ok to put it as the parent's directory of main. And these actions are not the business of Heroku.